# How to handle this with gunzip command

Tags: shell, unix

I am calling gunzip command in a loop based off a list of filenames in a file.  I would like it to both unzip the files and produce a list of the filenames.

I have tried

```
for i in `cat $file_name`
  do
  gunzip $i>>temp.txt
done
```

and

```
for i in `cat $file_name`
  do
  echo `gunzip $i`>>temp.txt
done
```

but this is not working.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but did you want `for i in \`cat $file_name\` ; do gunzip $i >> temp.txt ; done` ? Note the backquotes and semicolons.

Comment: I like `gone`. Perhaps use `done` instead.

Comment: Hi Chris as u know gunzip commands unzips the file, I want name of all the tagrget  files to be stored in a text file , Thanks

Comment: Do you want to loop over the *content* of `$file_name`? Because that's what you do. How is the list of files to unzip constructed?

Comment: Hi Tichodroma Hi have a file having list of .gz files and am calling that in a for loop and I want to store the names of files UNZIPED

Comment: try to do : $(gunzip -v $i >> temp.txt)

Answer (score 2):

Normally gunzip will extarct the file and remove the `.gz` extension

```
for i in `cat $file_name`
do
gunzip $i
echo $i|sed -e 's/\.gz//g' -e 's/\.tgz/.tar/g' >>temp.txt
done
```

Comment: i prefer echo ${i%.gz}

Comment: this doesn't catch the case when gunzip transforms `foo.tgz` to `foo.tar`. additionally `gunzip` could restore to the original filename (which might have nothing to do with the archive name) when called with the `-N` flag (though the OP did not ask about that)

Comment: your update makes `foo` from `foo.tgz` whereas it should really make `foo.tar`; probably do something like `sed -e 's/\.gz//g' -e 's/\.tgz/.tar/g'`

Answer (score 0):

There is many ways to solve your problem.

You can try this one, maybe not the better one:

```
    OUTPUT_TEMP_TXT="temp.txt"

    for GFILE in $(cat $file_name)
    do
        # Because there is only 1 file in a GZIP archive
        FILENAME=$(gunzip -v $GFILE 2>&1)
        RCODE=$?
        if [[ RCODE -eq 0 ]]
        then
            echo ${FILENAME} | cut -d':' -f1 | sed -e 's/\.gz$//gi' -e 's/\.tgz$/\.tar/gi' >> ${OUTPUT_TEMP_TXT}
        else
            echo "Can't extract $GFILE" >> ${OUTPUT_TEMP_TXT}
        fi
    done
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```bsh
cat list.txt | tee >(rev | cut -d'.' -f2- | rev > list.out) | xargs gunzip
```

triming `.gz` with `AWK`:

```bsh
cat list.txt | tee >(awk -F '.' '{$NF="";print}' > list.out) | xargs gunzip
```

with `sed`:

```bsh
cat list.txt | tee >(sed 's/\.gz$//' > list.out) | xargs gunzip
```

Comment: I think you wont use "-c" option because : 
          -c, --stdout      write on standard output, keep original files unchanged

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood the problem, my solution was for unpacking files and appending their content into another one.